# Failure with Alert, error = 42 when connecting to AWS IoT

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot, wolfssl

I am trying to replace the mbedTLS network layer with wolfSSL in the AWS IoT C SDK.

The simple subscribe_publish_sample demo that comes with the SDK works fine from a Linux host when using mbedTLS.

However, with my replacement of it with wolfSSL, I am getting a failure with error = 42, which seems to be that the server rejected the client certificate...?

The TCP connection to the AWS server is established, then the socket associated with the wolfSSL session, and the server's rootCA, client's certificate and private key added to the session (I removed the error handling code):

```
const int cert_container_format = SSL_FILETYPE_PEM;
WOLFSSL_METHOD * const method = wolfTLSv1_2_client_method();
hentry = gethostbyname(host_url);
memcpy(&sock_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, *hentry->h_addr_list, hentry->h_length);
sock_addr.sin_family = hentry->h_addrtype;
socket_fd = socket(sock_addr.sin_family, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
sock_addr.sin_port = htons(host_port);
connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sock_addr, sizeof(sock_addr));
wolfSSL_Init();
ssl_ctx = wolfSSL_CTX_new(method);
session = wolfSSL_new(ssl_ctx);
result = wolfSSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ssl_ctx, root_ca_filepath, NULL);
result = wolfSSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ssl_ctx, dev_prvkey_filepath,
                                         cert_container_format);
result = wolfSSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ssl_ctx, dev_cert_filepath, cert_container_format);
wolfSSL_set_fd(session, socket_fd);
result = wolfSSL_connect(session);
```

Here is the full dump with debugging enabled:

```
AWS IoT SDK Version 2.1.1-

DEBUG:   main L#166 rootCA /home/ben/git/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/samples/linux/subscribe_publish_sample/../../../certs/aws-rootca.pem
DEBUG:   main L#167 clientCRT /home/ben/git/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/samples/linux/subscribe_publish_sample/../../../certs/aws-cert.pem
DEBUG:   main L#168 clientKey /home/ben/git/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/samples/linux/subscribe_publish_sample/../../../certs/aws-prvkey.pem
Connecting...
URL: a3i4lmgkxatoyr.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
name: dualstack.iotmoonraker-u-elb-1w8qnw1336zq-1186348092.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com, len: 4, type: 2
alternate names: 
    a3i4lmgkxatoyr.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
    iotmoonraker.us-west-2.prod.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
addresses: 
    52.10.19.111
    52.41.23.91
    34.210.178.78
    35.165.44.84
    52.25.57.203
    35.160.71.83
wolfSSL Entering wolfSSL_Init
wolfSSL Entering wolfCrypt_Init
wolfSSL Entering WOLFSSL_CTX_new_ex
wolfSSL Entering wolfSSL_CertManagerNew
wolfSSL Leaving WOLFSSL_CTX_new, return 0
wolfSSL Entering SSL_new
wolfSSL Leaving SSL_new, return 0
DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#271 root CA file: /home/ben/git/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/samples/linux/subscribe_publish_sample/../../../certs/aws-rootca.pem

wolfSSL Entering wolfSSL_CTX_load_verify_locations
Getting dynamic buffer
Processing CA PEM file
wolfSSL Entering PemToDer
Adding a CA
wolfSSL Entering GetExplicitVersion
wolfSSL Entering GetSerialNumber
Got Cert Header
wolfSSL Entering GetAlgoId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
Got Algo ID
Getting Cert Name
Getting Cert Name
Got Subject Name
wolfSSL Entering GetAlgoId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
Got Key
Parsed Past Key
wolfSSL Entering DecodeCertExtensions
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeBasicCaConstraint
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeKeyUsage
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeSubjKeyId
wolfSSL Entering GetAlgoId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
    Parsed new CA
    Freeing Parsed CA
    Freeing der CA
        OK Freeing der CA
wolfSSL Leaving AddCA, return 0
   Processed a CA
Processed at least one valid CA. Other stuff OK
DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#280 dev private key file: /home/ben/git/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/samples/linux/subscribe_publish_sample/../../../certs/aws-prvkey.pem

wolfSSL Entering wolfSSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file
Getting dynamic buffer
wolfSSL Entering PemToDer
DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#290 dev certificate file: /home/ben/git/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/samples/linux/subscribe_publish_sample/../../../certs/aws-cert.pem

wolfSSL Entering wolfSSL_CTX_use_certificate_file
Getting dynamic buffer
wolfSSL Entering PemToDer
Checking cert signature type
wolfSSL Entering GetExplicitVersion
wolfSSL Entering GetSerialNumber
Got Cert Header
wolfSSL Entering GetAlgoId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
Got Algo ID
Getting Cert Name
Getting Cert Name
Got Subject Name
wolfSSL Entering GetAlgoId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
Got Key
Not ECDSA cert signature
wolfSSL Entering SSL_set_fd
wolfSSL Entering SSL_set_read_fd
wolfSSL Leaving SSL_set_read_fd, return 1
wolfSSL Entering SSL_set_write_fd
wolfSSL Leaving SSL_set_write_fd, return 1
wolfSSL Entering SSL_connect()
Adding signature algorithms extension
growing output buffer

Signature Algorithms extension to write
Elliptic Curves extension to write
Shrinking output buffer

connect state: CLIENT_HELLO_SENT
growing input buffer

received record layer msg
wolfSSL Entering DoHandShakeMsg()
wolfSSL Entering DoHandShakeMsgType
processing server hello
wolfSSL Entering VerifyClientSuite
wolfSSL Leaving DoHandShakeMsgType(), return 0
wolfSSL Leaving DoHandShakeMsg(), return 0
More messages in record
received record layer msg
wolfSSL Entering DoHandShakeMsg()
wolfSSL Entering DoHandShakeMsgType
processing certificate
wolfSSL Entering ProcessPeerCerts
Loading peer's cert chain
    Put another cert into chain
    Put another cert into chain
wolfSSL Entering GetExplicitVersion
wolfSSL Entering GetSerialNumber
Got Cert Header
wolfSSL Entering GetAlgoId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
Got Algo ID
Getting Cert Name
Getting Cert Name
Got Subject Name
wolfSSL Entering GetAlgoId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
Got Key
Parsed Past Key
wolfSSL Entering DecodeCertExtensions
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeAuthInfo
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeBasicCaConstraint
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
Certificate Policy extension not supported yet.
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeCrlDist
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeKeyUsage
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeAltNames
    Unsupported name type, skipping
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeSubjKeyId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeAuthKeyId
wolfSSL Entering GetAlgoId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
About to verify certificate signature
wolfSSL Entering ConfirmSignature
wolfSSL Leaving ConfirmSignature, return 0
Adding CA from chain
Adding a CA
wolfSSL Entering GetExplicitVersion
wolfSSL Entering GetSerialNumber
Got Cert Header
wolfSSL Entering GetAlgoId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
Got Algo ID
Getting Cert Name
Getting Cert Name
Got Subject Name
wolfSSL Entering GetAlgoId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
Got Key
Parsed Past Key
wolfSSL Entering DecodeCertExtensions
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeAuthInfo
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeBasicCaConstraint
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
Certificate Policy extension not supported yet.
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeCrlDist
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeKeyUsage
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeAltNames
    Unsupported name type, skipping
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeSubjKeyId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeAuthKeyId
wolfSSL Entering GetAlgoId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
    Parsed new CA
    Freeing Parsed CA
    Freeing der CA
        OK Freeing der CA
wolfSSL Leaving AddCA, return 0
Verifying Peer's cert
wolfSSL Entering GetExplicitVersion
wolfSSL Entering GetSerialNumber
Got Cert Header
wolfSSL Entering GetAlgoId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
Got Algo ID
Getting Cert Name
Getting Cert Name
Got Subject Name
wolfSSL Entering GetAlgoId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
Got Key
Parsed Past Key
wolfSSL Entering DecodeCertExtensions
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeAltNames
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeBasicCaConstraint
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeKeyUsage
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeExtKeyUsage
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
Certificate Policy extension not supported yet.
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeAuthKeyId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeCrlDist
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering DecodeAuthInfo
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
wolfSSL Entering GetAlgoId
wolfSSL Entering GetObjectId()
About to verify certificate signature
wolfSSL Entering ConfirmSignature
wolfSSL Leaving ConfirmSignature, return 0
Verified Peer's cert
wolfSSL Leaving ProcessPeerCerts, return 0
wolfSSL Leaving DoHandShakeMsgType(), return 0
wolfSSL Leaving DoHandShakeMsg(), return 0
More messages in record
received record layer msg
wolfSSL Entering DoHandShakeMsg()
wolfSSL Entering DoHandShakeMsgType
processing server key exchange
wolfSSL Entering DoServerKeyExchange
wolfSSL Entering EccVerify
wolfSSL Leaving EccVerify, return 0
wolfSSL Leaving DoServerKeyExchange, return 0
wolfSSL Leaving DoHandShakeMsgType(), return 0
wolfSSL Leaving DoHandShakeMsg(), return 0
More messages in record
received record layer msg
wolfSSL Entering DoHandShakeMsg()
wolfSSL Entering DoHandShakeMsgType
processing certificate request
wolfSSL Leaving DoHandShakeMsgType(), return 0
wolfSSL Leaving DoHandShakeMsg(), return 0
More messages in record
received record layer msg
wolfSSL Entering DoHandShakeMsg()
wolfSSL Entering DoHandShakeMsgType
processing server hello done
wolfSSL Leaving DoHandShakeMsgType(), return 0
wolfSSL Leaving DoHandShakeMsg(), return 0
connect state: HELLO_AGAIN
connect state: HELLO_AGAIN_REPLY
connect state: FIRST_REPLY_DONE
growing output buffer

Shrinking output buffer

sent: certificate
connect state: FIRST_REPLY_FIRST
wolfSSL Entering SendClientKeyExchange
wolfSSL Entering EccMakeKey
wolfSSL Leaving EccMakeKey, return 0
wolfSSL Entering EccSharedSecret
wolfSSL Leaving EccSharedSecret, return 0
growing output buffer

Shrinking output buffer

wolfSSL Leaving SendClientKeyExchange, return 0
sent: client key exchange
connect state: FIRST_REPLY_SECOND
wolfSSL Entering SendCertificateVerify
sent: certificate verify
connect state: FIRST_REPLY_THIRD
growing output buffer

Shrinking output buffer

sent: change cipher spec
connect state: FIRST_REPLY_FOURTH
growing output buffer

wolfSSL Entering BuildMessage
wolfSSL Leaving BuildMessage, return 0
Shrinking output buffer

sent: finished
connect state: FINISHED_DONE
received record layer msg
got ALERT!
Got alert
wolfSSL error occurred, error = 42
wolfSSL error occurred, error = -313
ERROR: iot_tls_connect L#326 wolfSSL Entering SSL_get_error
wolfSSL Leaving SSL_get_error, return -313
failure creating SSL connection to server [-313]
wolfSSL Entering SSL_free
CTX ref count not 0 yet, no free
Shrinking input buffer

wolfSSL Leaving SSL_free, return 0
wolfSSL Entering SSL_CTX_free
CTX ref count down to 0, doing full free
wolfSSL Entering wolfSSL_CertManagerFree
wolfSSL Leaving SSL_CTX_free, return 0
wolfSSL Entering wolfSSL_Cleanup
wolfSSL Entering wolfCrypt_Cleanup
wolfSSL Entering SSL_shutdown()
wolfSSL Entering wolfSSL_Cleanup
ERROR: main L#197 Error(-4) connecting to a3i4lmgkxatoyr.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:8883
```

And here is the wireshark capture while running the demo:

```
  324 43.301028126  147.34.2.16 → 134.86.9.42  DNS 546 Standard query response 0x6223 A a3i4lmgkxatoyr.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com CNAME iotmoonraker.us-west-2.prod.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com CNAME dualstack.iotmoonraker-u-elb-1w8qnw1336zq-1186348092.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com A 52.10.19.111 A 52.25.57.203 A 35.165.44.84 A 35.160.71.83 A 34.210.178.78 A 52.41.23.91 NS ns-560.awsdns-06.net NS ns-1475.awsdns-56.org NS ns-1
769.awsdns-29.co.uk NS ns-332.awsdns-41.com A 205.251.198.233 AAAA 2600:9000:5306:e900::1 A 205.251.193.76 AAAA 2600:9000:5301:4c00::1
  325 43.301247236  134.86.9.42 → 52.10.19.111 TCP 74 40282 → 8883 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1333683979 TSecr=0 WS=128
  328 43.412499273 52.10.19.111 → 134.86.9.42  TCP 66 8883 → 40282 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1360 SACK_PERM=1 WS=256
  329 43.412535130  134.86.9.42 → 52.10.19.111 TCP 54 40282 → 8883 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=29312 Len=0
  336 43.413988506  134.86.9.42 → 52.10.19.111 SSL 196 Client Hello
  339 43.414370228 52.10.19.111 → 134.86.9.42  TCP 60 8883 → 40282 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=143 Win=5888 Len=0
  341 43.533620599 52.10.19.111 → 134.86.9.42  TCP 1414 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
  342 43.533659332  134.86.9.42 → 52.10.19.111 TCP 54 40282 → 8883 [ACK] Seq=143 Ack=1361 Win=32128 Len=0
  343 43.533830301 52.10.19.111 → 134.86.9.42  TLSv1.2 1283 Server Hello, Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Certificate Request, Server Hello Done
  344 43.533876234  134.86.9.42 → 52.10.19.111 TCP 54 40282 → 8883 [ACK] Seq=143 Ack=2590 Win=35072 Len=0
  349 43.545353568  134.86.9.42 → 52.10.19.111 TLSv1.2 66 Certificate
  350 43.545651974 52.10.19.111 → 134.86.9.42  TCP 60 8883 → 40282 [ACK] Seq=2590 Ack=155 Win=5888 Len=0
  351 43.552906179  134.86.9.42 → 52.10.19.111 TLSv1.2 129 Client Key Exchange
  352 43.553226294 52.10.19.111 → 134.86.9.42  TCP 60 8883 → 40282 [ACK] Seq=2590 Ack=230 Win=5888 Len=0
  353 43.553237461  134.86.9.42 → 52.10.19.111 TLSv1.2 60 Change Cipher Spec
  354 43.553645295 52.10.19.111 → 134.86.9.42  TCP 60 8883 → 40282 [ACK] Seq=2590 Ack=236 Win=5888 Len=0
  355 43.553661141  134.86.9.42 → 52.10.19.111 TLSv1.2 99 Hello Request, Hello Request
  356 43.554058924 52.10.19.111 → 134.86.9.42  TCP 60 8883 → 40282 [ACK] Seq=2590 Ack=281 Win=5888 Len=0
  367 43.659283864 52.10.19.111 → 134.86.9.42  TLSv1.2 61 Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Bad Certificate)
  368 43.659391034  134.86.9.42 → 52.10.19.111 TCP 54 40282 → 8883 [FIN, ACK] Seq=281 Ack=2597 Win=35072 Len=0
  369 43.659472966 52.10.19.111 → 134.86.9.42  TCP 60 8883 → 40282 [FIN, ACK] Seq=2597 Ack=281 Win=5888 Len=0
  371 43.659485750  134.86.9.42 → 52.10.19.111 TCP 54 40282 → 8883 [ACK] Seq=282 Ack=2598 Win=35072 Len=0
  372 43.659701144 52.10.19.111 → 134.86.9.42  TCP 60 8883 → 40282 [ACK] Seq=2598 Ack=282 Win=5888 Len=0
```

The exact same certificates/keys work with when using mbedTLS.

I'm obviously missing something here, might be obvious to someone too, but I'm not seeing it.

(also posted on wolfSSL forums [https://www.wolfssl.com/forums/topic1122-failure-with-alert-error-42-when-connecting-to-aws-iot.html], but I thought I'd broden the audience)

Comment: Ah, 42: The answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and **Everything**.

Comment: My guess is if they're returning 42 for the error#, it means at some point in the hierarchy of calls, what the real error is got lost. While we can maybe assume that most users of an SDK would know what 42 means ... it's kind of a cruel joke for those who might not ...

Comment: Or maybe the dev didn't know what 42 meant ... should have skipped it for usability purposes ;-) kind of like 'what error is good enough to get #13?'

Comment: If you have any future questions regarding a product of wolfSSL please feel free to reach out to wolfSSL anytime at support@wolfssl.com. We are always happy to help and offer free presales and open source support.

DISCLAIMER: I work for wolfSSL Inc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it turns out that I had to load the certs/key *before* creating the SSL session, not *after*:

```
ssl_ctx = wolfSSL_CTX_new(method);
result = wolfSSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ssl_ctx, root_ca_filepath, NULL);
result = wolfSSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ssl_ctx, dev_prvkey_filepath,
                                         cert_container_format);
result = wolfSSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ssl_ctx, dev_cert_filepath, cert_container_format);
session = wolfSSL_new(ssl_ctx);
```

instead of:

```
ssl_ctx = wolfSSL_CTX_new(method);
session = wolfSSL_new(ssl_ctx);
result = wolfSSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ssl_ctx, root_ca_filepath, NULL);
result = wolfSSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ssl_ctx, dev_prvkey_filepath,
                                         cert_container_format);
result = wolfSSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ssl_ctx, dev_cert_filepath, cert_container_format);
```

Comment: Hi @Ben, and any others reading this. Think of the CTX as a factory. The factory is used to crank out SSL objects. An SSL object is created on the call to wolfSSL_new(); At that point if you wish to modify that SSL object you have to switch from using the ```wolfSSL_CTX_``` API's to the SSL ONLY API's IE: ```wolfSSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file``` equivalent is ```wolfSSL_use_PrivateKey_file``` AFTER the SSL object is created! This allows custom modification of the object post creation. The ```_CTX_``` API's modify the factory, SSL ONLY API's modify a single object after creation. Make sense?

Comment: Anytime! If anything else comes up and you prefer to post the question on stack for the benefit of others feel free to do so and then shoot an email to support@wolfssl.com with a link to your stack question. One of our engineers will be happy to post a response!

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a failure to negotiate a cipher to use.

This thread may help you solve this. Relevant parts:

"-313" means that the server has sent back a Fatal Alert to the client.  If this happens after the ClientHello message is sent, this most likely means that the client is not broadcasting support for a cipher suite or extension that the server requires.

- If using ECC, the server requires the Supported Curves Extension to be enabled.  Compile wolfSSL with "--enable-supportedcurves" to resolve.
- wolfSSL has static key cipher suites disabled by default for security.  Please see note at the top of the README for instructions on re-enabling static-key cipher suites if your server requires them.

Use nmap to determine which cipher suites that Amazon is supporting and then enable the best ones in WolfSSL.

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 <host>
```

[WolfSSL: Error -313](https://www.wolfssl.com/forums/topic839-solved-err-313-revcd-alert-fatal-error.html)

Comment: Yes, but the 42 code means that the server rejected the certificate: `bad_certificate = 42` and if you look at the wireshark dump: `367 52.10.19.111 → 134.86.9.42 TLSv1.2 61 Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Bad Certificate)` and as per the TLS 1.2 RFC: `bad_certificate A certificate was corrupt, contained signatures that did not verify correctly, etc.`

I checked the list of ciphers supported by wolfSSL at runtime, and the list of ciphers proposed by AWS, and some of them match, so I suppose they should be able to negotiate one...?